# how to reorder the search path?

Tags: r, tidyverse, r-environment

I want to attach an environment (package or other) to position 2 and I want it to stay there.

I can use `library` with `pos=3` to ensure this most of the time, but I have issues with `tidyverse` :

```
search()
# [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"    
# [4] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
# [7] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"        
# [10] "package:base" 

something <- list()
attach(something)
library(tidyverse,pos = 3)
search()
# [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:forcats"   "package:stringr"  
# [4] "package:dplyr"     "package:purrr"     "package:readr"    
# [7] "package:tidyr"     "package:tibble"    "package:ggplot2"  
# [10] "something"         "package:tidyverse" "tools:rstudio"    
# [13] "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices"
# [16] "package:utils"     "package:datasets"  "package:methods"  
# [19] "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

`tidyverse` attaches its children packages at `pos = 2`, I want a `search` path starting with :

```
search()
# [1] ".GlobalEnv" "something" "package:forcats"...
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it by defining 2 custom functions, `move_pkg_env` moves a `package:*` environment, and `move_env` (using `move_pkg_env`) moves any environment in the search path as long as there are only `package:*` environments between its position and the destination :

Here's how to use it :

```
something <- list()
attach(something)
library(tidyverse,pos = 3)

search()
# [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:forcats"   "package:stringr"  
# [4] "package:dplyr"     "package:purrr"     "package:readr"    
# [7] "package:tidyr"     "package:tibble"    "package:ggplot2"  
# [10] "something"         "package:tidyverse" "tools:rstudio"    
# [13] "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices"
# [16] "package:utils"     "package:datasets"  "package:methods"  
# [19] "Autoloads"         "package:base"

move_env("something", 2)

search()
# [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "something"         "package:forcats"  
# [4] "package:stringr"   "package:dplyr"     "package:purrr"    
# [7] "package:readr"     "package:tidyr"     "package:tibble"   
# [10] "package:ggplot2"   "package:tidyverse" "tools:rstudio"    
# [13] "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices"
# [16] "package:utils"     "package:datasets"  "package:methods"  
# [19] "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

**the functions :**

```
move_pkg_env <- function(env, at, after = FALSE){
  if(is.numeric(env)) env <- search()[env]
  if(!startsWith(env, "package:"))
    stop("env must be a 'package::*' environment")
  if(!env %in% search())
    stop(paste(env,"is not on the search path"))

  pkg <- sub('package:','',env)
  pos <- which(env == search())[1]
  if(is.character(at)){
    at = which(at == search())[1]
    if(is.na(at)) stop(paste(pkg,"is not on the search path"))
  }
  detach(env,character.only = TRUE)
  at <- at + after - (pos < at)
  suppressWarnings(library(pkg,pos=at,
                           warn.conflicts = FALSE, 
                           quietly = TRUE,
                           character.only = TRUE,
                           verbose = FALSE))
}

move_env <- function(env, at, after = FALSE){
  if(is.numeric(env)) env <- search()[env]
  if(!env %in% search())
    stop(paste(env,"is not on the search path"))

  if(is.character(at)){
    at = which(at == search())[1]
    if(is.na(at)) stop(paste(pkg,"is not on the search path"))
  }
  at <- at + after

  pos <- which(env == search())[1]
  while(pos > at){
    move_pkg_env(pos-1,pos+1)
    pos <- which(env == search())[1] 
  }
  while(pos < at){
    move_pkg_env(pos+1,pos-1)
    pos <- which(env == search())[1] 
  }
}
```

**relevant github issue**

https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse/issues/159